# write page counter in pdf footer but pass to render start number (first page is not 1 and > 1)

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo, jaxp, apache-fop

i use an old fop lib version 0.20.5

I have an xsl:fo with

```
<fo:block text-align="end">

       Page number :<fo:page-number />

</fo:block>
```

this is in the footer

I need to create a PDF with a initial number > 1 and for ex. 10 or 11 or some other else..

So the first page begin with 10, the secondo eith 11 and so on..

I need to pass this number as parameter from jsp web page to my bean/java classes that call the fop rendering

I implement a CustomRender (it implemem the class org.apache.fop.render.Renderer)

and i override tese two method:

```
public void render(Page page, OutputStream outputStream){
throws IOException, FOPException {
   page.setNumber(pageCount);
System.out.println("##@@## Rendering page " + page.getNumber());
pageCount++;
renderer.render(page, outputStream);
}



public void renderPage(Page page){
page.setNumber(pageCount);
System.out.println("@@##@@ Rendering page " + page.getNumber());
pageCount++;
renderer.renderPage(page);
}
```

but page.setNumber(pageCount); doesn't seem to work!

How can I do this work?

Thanks in advice!

Roberto

Comment: That is an *oooold* version, over half a decade old... Have you tried switching to [FOP 2.0](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/)? It will also get you a lot of XSL-FO 1.1. I haven't used that version in years, but you may try the [FOP Mailing list](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/maillist.html), perhaps some developer of the time is still around.

Comment: Does that old version of FOP not support initial-page-number? That is how you would typically implement this. <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="10"> ... you could even set that number in the transform process through a parameter passed in.

Comment: yes initial-number work! 
 And from what I can read in FOP 0.20.5 doc (see [1]), this was implemented.
 Not sure however if it worked perfectly, since FOP redesign (starting
 from v0.9x), 0.20.x remains unmaintained.

 [1] https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/tags/fop-0_20_5/src/documentation/content/xdocs/compliance.xml

Comment: If that worked, I posted an answer to close out this question.

Answer (score 1):

Does that old version of FOP not support initial-page-number? That is how you would typically implement this. <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="10"> ... you could even set that number in the transform process through a parameter passed in.